# Turn each element of an array into its own array

Tags: arrays, ruby

I can turn something like

```
[0, 3]
```

into

```
[[0], [3]]
```

I can't find anything that will then turn that into

```
[0][3]
```

Is there a way to do this? Or is there a way to iterate through the original array and make each element its own array, without creating any subarrays?

Comment: What is `[0][3]`? Could you describe how you would make it "manually"?

Comment: Basically I'm using gets to find where a player wants to put something on a 7x7 board. I want them to be able to input "0, 3" (or whatever) and convert that to [0][3] so it can be displayed correctly on the game board

Comment: So you want to parse a row and column out of a `row, column` string? `row, column = '0, 3'.split(',').map(&:to_i)`. Getting items by index with the `[]` operator as in `a[1]` has nothing to do with an array literal like `[1]`.

Comment: Your question does not make sense at all.

Comment: `arr = [[0], [3]]; arr.first[arr.last.first] #=> [0][3] => nil`.

Comment: @RyanO'Hara, `[0][3]` is the element of `[0]` at index `3`: `nil`. :-)

Comment: @CarySwoveland I understand that such conversion is not possible. But I think his objective behind the question is only to access the element of board corresponding to input co-ordinates.

Answer (score 1):

In Ruby 2.3 you can use [`Array#dig`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/Array.html#method-i-dig):

```
arr = [ [ "a", "b", "c" ],
        [ "m", "n", "o"] ]

puts arr.dig(1, 2)
# => o
```

In order to use that with your input array, use the splat operator:

```
args = [ 1, 2 ]
puts arr.dig(*args)
# => o
```

Comment: Awesome. plus one for `dig`. I didn't know that such a method exists. Seems better than my `eval` appraoch.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, there is a problem in question that needs to be corrected. You need to make clear on what you mean by `[0][3]`. Is it string, array, reference to array or what ?!

But, I guess I could understand your objective from the comment you made:

> Basically I'm using gets to find where a player wants to put something on a 7x7 board. I want them to be able to input "0,3" (or whatever) and convert that to [0][3] so it can be displayed correctly on the game board

So I assume that given an multi dimensional array of lets say 3X3. Now when the user inputs the string `0,2`, you want to access the corresponding element from the array.

Well, this can be done: A messy way:

```
array = [[1,2,3],[5,6,7],[8,9,10]]
input = gets.strip
#input is: 1,2
command = "array[" + input.split(",").join("][") + "]"
# command: array[0][2] # I guess, this string is want you wanted !
eval(command)
# 7
```

A better way:

```
array = [[1,2,3],[5,6,7],[8,9,10]]
input = gets.strip
#input is: 1,2
x, y = input.split(",").map(&:to_i)
array[x][y]
# 7
```

Documentation of `eval` method is [here](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.1/Kernel.html#method-i-eval).

I would encourage you to please update your question appropriately so that people don't vote it. Its a legitimate question, but only asked wrongly.

Hope it helps :)

Comment: I think what he means by [0][3] is the reference to array (board). Ok right that such conversion is possible because [0][3] #= nil obviously. But what purpose will it solve.

Answer (score -1):

```
[0,3].map { |e| [e]  }
```

try this